# Comparing Moran's value between different variables in same geographie

Tags: spatial-correlation

let's suppose I have a dataset with 3 different variables (features) for the same geographie and then calculate the Moran's values for each one. All my variables have a p-values<0.05. Can I compare this variables and says: the higher the Moran's value, the more significant is that variable in relation to the others?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do those comparisons. You can calculate Moran´s I for each variable and get a *p-value*, as you indicated. Let's suppose this process runs in R using the [spdep](/questions/tagged/spdep) package. Those *p-values* are for 'the test for the alternative that $I > E(I)$, not to compare between different Moran´s I values.

You may find more information about this in 'Bivand, Roger S., Edzer J. Pebesma, Virgilio Gómez-Rubio, and Edzer Jan Pebesma. Applied spatial data analysis with R. Vol. 747248717. New York: Springer, 2008. p. 260'

Hope this helps, and I would look forward to seeing how you figure this out.